# Return name of place in geocoder result

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

Is it possible to return the name of the place in the results using google's geocoder?

I realize that the documentation doesn't show it as a returned result.

How would i go about receiving the name?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the geocoder results to feed a [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) query.